# SQL request: Count average value of each different rows

Tags: sql, join, count, request, average

I have 2 tables: dish and rating. Dish:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pizza |
| 2 | wok |
| 3 | sushi |

Rating:

| dish | rate | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

**In dish**: id is primary.
**In rating**: dish is foreign key to dish.id table and user is foreign key also but don't worry about user.

So i need to count average rating of each dish.

It will look like this:

| dishID | aver. rate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 |

i dunno how to write such a hard SQL request
need help :3

Answer (score 0):

use left join and group by clause.

```
select 
    d.id as dishid,
    avg(r.rate) as "aver. rate"
    dish d 
    left join Rating r on d.id =r.dishid
    group by d.id
```

Answer (score 0):

That's basically a `LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP BY`.
Very important here is to use `COALESCE`.

Why that?

If there is no rating for a dish, you will get 0 as result instead of `NULL` (which is intended according to your description).

So your query will be like this:

```
SELECT 
  d.id AS dishId, AVG(COALESCE(r.rate,0)) AS "aver. rate"
FROM dish d 
  LEFT JOIN rating r 
  ON d.id = r.dish
GROUP BY d.id;
```